# How to use 'Count', based on a particular column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query and which give the count greater than 1, but what I expect is I need the result to be based on particular column(Rollno.) How to achieve it.

**Table Studies**

```
   NAME            RollNo        DeptType      InternalStaff_1     InternalStaff_2
-----------     -----------     -----------    ---------------     --------------- 
   Anu              5            CompSci        Eve                  Antony
   Joy             13            Architecture   Elizabeth            George
   Adam             2            Mech           Grady                Lisa 
   Adam             2            Mech           Grady                Kim
   Anu              5            CompSci        Eve                  Antony
```

The below query gives me Count but not as expected

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.Name
, S.RollNo
, COUNT(S.RollNo) AS [Count]
, S.DeptType
, S.InternalStaff_1
, S.InternalStaff_2
FROM DataMining.dbo.Studies S
WHERE StartDate >= '20210325'--@StartDate
AND StartDate <= '20210407'--@EndDate
GROUP BY S.Name, S.RollNo, S.DeptType, S.InternalStaff_1, S.InternalStaff_2
HAVING COUNT(S.RollNo) > 1
ORDER BY RollNo
```

The query gave me the below result

```
  NAME            RollNo          Count         DeptType      InternalStaff_1     InternalStaff_2
-----------     -----------     -----------    -----------    ---------------     --------------- 
   Anu              5              2            CompSci        Eve                  Antony
```

But the expected result is

```
  NAME            RollNo          Count         DeptType      InternalStaff_1     InternalStaff_2
-----------     -----------     -----------    -----------    ---------------     --------------- 
   Anu              5              2            CompSci        Eve                  Antony
   Adam             2              2            Mech           Grady                NULL
```

As you can see the expected result is having a different InternalStaff_2 name for Adam which is not considered on the present result.

May I know how to over come this?

**Note:**  I need the results to be displayed based on `Rollno` but I also need the `InternalStaff_2` to be included in the result.

Comment: It's because you are grouping on `InternalStaff_2` and Adam has two different internal staff values so it's count will be one and will appear twice in the results.

Comment: Explain how your expected results come to have a value of `NULL` for `InternalStaff_2`

Comment: @PeterSmith As we use count and If we didn't use it in the grouping it throws error. Any ways to over come that. I need the ```InternalStaff_2``` also to be included in results but the result should be based on the ```RollNo```

Comment: @Stu As it is my expected result I just gave a random data. Based on the ```RollNo``` I need the results to be displayed but I also need the ```InternalStaff_2``` to be included in the result.

Comment: You are asking sql server to `group by` that column - that column has 2 distinct values for Adam resulting in 2 groups of 1 row. You could aggregate `internalstaff_2` with a `min` or `max` function. If you were using a modern version of Sql Server this is easily solvable with `string_agg`

Comment: DISTINCT does nothing useful here. Stop throwing it into queries as a kludge to fix logic errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If I understand correctly, you want `NULL` if the internal staff columns do not match.  That would be:

```
SELECT S.Name, S.RollNo, COUNT(*) AS [Count], S.DeptType,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(S.InternalStaff_1) = MAX(S.InternalStaff_1) THEN MIN(S.InternalStaff_1) END) as InternalStaff_1,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(S.InternalStaff_2) = MAX(S.InternalStaff_2) THEN MIN(S.InternalStaff_2) END) as InternalStaff_2
FROM DataMining.dbo.Studies S
WHERE StartDate >= '20210325' AND --@StartDate
      StartDate <= '20210407'     --@EndDate
GROUP BY S.Name, S.RollNo, S.DeptType
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY RollNo;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5d50adef00c07d84f16cd463b24f22c) is a db<>fiddle that shows that this basically works.

Comment: This gives me a very different result, But yes you understood correctly. I'm not looking for null, but irrespective of other columns when if more than 1  ```rollno``` repeats I need those to be in result. Is there a way to use all the columns mentioned in the query but not in Group by?!

Comment: @RealGem . . . I added a db<>fiddle that shows that the code basically works.

Comment: Thankyou. That was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

like this?
I do not confirm your needs, but the internalstaff_2 column can refer to STRING_AGG() to replace the nested subquery in the following script.

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.Name
       , S.RollNo
       , COUNT(S.RollNo) AS [Count]
       , S.DeptType
       , S.InternalStaff_1
       , (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT InternalStaff_2) = 1 THEN MIN(InternalStaff_2) ELSE null END
          FROM #temp AS i
          WHERE i.NAME = S.NAME and i.RollNo = S.RollNo and i.DeptType = S.DeptType and i.InternalStaff_1 = S.InternalStaff_1) as InternalStaff_2
FROM #temp S
GROUP BY S.[Name], S.RollNo, S.DeptType, S.InternalStaff_1
HAVING COUNT(S.RollNo) > 1
ORDER BY RollNo
```